# Generating an RSS feed from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, rss

Here is the code for my rss.php file:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml"); ?>
<?php echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"; ?>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "database_user", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error()); 

$cityquery = "SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$cityresult = mysql_query($cityquery);
$cityrow = mysql_fetch_row($cityresult);
$city = $cityrow[0];

$servicequery = "SELECT * FROM services ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$serviceresult = mysql_query($servicequery);
$servicerow = mysql_fetch_row($serviceresult);
$service = $servicerow[0];
?>

<?php
$servicename = ucwords($service);
$cityname = ucwords($city);
$servicelink = str_replace(" ","-",$service);
$citylink = str_replace(" ","-",$city);
?>

<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link>http://local.mywebsite.com</link>
  <description>This is my description.</description>
  <pubDate><?echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s');?></pubDate>

<?php foreach( range( 1, 25 ) as $i ): ?>

<item>
    <title><?php echo $servicename; ?> in <?php echo $cityname; ?></title>
    <pubDate><?echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s');?></pubDate>
    <link>http://local.mywebsite.com/<?php echo $servicelink; ?>/<?php echo $citylink; ?></link>
    <description><?php echo $servicename; ?> in <?php echo $cityname; ?> - <?php echo $servicename; ?> <?php echo $cityname; ?> - <?php echo $cityname; ?> <?php echo $servicename; ?> - <?php echo $cityname; ?> - <?php echo $servicename; ?></description>
</item>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</channel>
</rss>
```

As you can see from the code above, this RSS feed is getting a list of cities and services from a MySQL database.  The RSS feed has 25 items in it, the problem is that they are all exactly the same item.  What needs to be changed to basically create a loop so that each item actually shows a different city/service from the database?

Please feel free to let me know if anyone needs something clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `mysql_fetch_array` in a while loop, and echo them.

Append something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['cityname'];
}
```

The mysql_* functions is deprecated and will be removed, so you should take a look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Using these functions the right way will also protect you from SQL injections and other vulnerabilities.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit further where in my code I'd need to implement that at?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post in a minute with an update. The `$row['cityname']` where cityname is the name of your column.

Comment: How exactly do the cities and services table work together, by the way? Judging by your code, it seems as one service belong to a city. Am I correct? How do you constrain those two in the database?

Comment: Cities and services are completely separate from each other and can be paired up in any way.  We offer every service in every city.

Comment: So you want to output cityname - and then all services, for each city?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - basically each item in the rss feed will generate one random city name and one random service.